# Jquery pageX and screenX from event is negative on second monitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While my function works on my first monitor like it should on my second monitor all coordinates of event are negative. Like its referent point is still on my primary monitor. Event is triggered on drag and drop from html5.

```
function endDnD(e) { 
   var parentOff = $(this).parent().offset();
   console.log(e);
   console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY, parentOff.left, parentOff.top);
   var posX = e.screenX - parentOff.left;
   var posY = e.pageY - parentOff.top; 
   $(this).css('left', posX);
   $(this).css('top', posY);
}
```

Comment: That's because `screen` generally doesn't know that you have multiple screens, it's based on the "primary monitor".

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add this into your equation:

```
 window.screen.availLeft
```

that returns a 0 value if it's the primary screen  (left screen by default) or the width of the primary screen as the starting point of the right screen.

look for information and example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availLeft

Note that while this is information on Mozilla's site it should also work for other popular browsers

Comment: The support info for this is very sketchy. The MDN doesn't mention browser support and it's not mentioned on caniuse.com. So I'd use this with caution

Comment: checked in IE9, not available there

Comment: Ie9 .. Isn't that considered eol in a few weeks? Who is even still using that that's compliant? Really scraping the barrel here.

Answer (score 1):

To get an X coordinate on the current screen you can use:

```
e.clientX
```

instead of `e.pageX`. That will return a `x > 0` value.